# Text Selection Contextual Actionbar disappearing on autoscroll

Tags: android, textselection, contextual-action-bar

I'm witnessing some very weird behaviour I think might be related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643548/extending-text-selection-contextual-action-bar-in-android).

My basic layout is a ListView with 1 header that contains a selectable TextView. When the entire ListView (header+items) fits in less than the screen and I select text in the selectable TextView, everything works like you'd expect: the Contextual Actionbar appears, the word I longpressed is highlighted, the "selection-triangle-sliders" appear.

My problem is: when the ListView does NOT fit in the screen, selecting text in the selectable TextView causes the Contextual Actionbar to appear and immediately disappear, leaving the word I longpressed highlighted but with the "selection-triangle-sliders" gone, my ListView slightly scrolled down, and the app in some weird "state" that I need to press Back to get out of.

My questions are:

1) Am I correct in assuming that the auto-scrolling of my ListView is causing a loss of focus of my selectable TextView and destroying the Contextual Actionbar or is there something else going on?

2) More importantly, how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a fix for that?

Comment: nope :/ ended up changing the design